# AngularJS making ng-bind-html to a dynamically constructed object name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to set the within the HTML code a binding to a dynamically created name, something like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="MyVariable_{{counter}}">
```

and in the controller I'm using the following code:

```
        var the_string = 'MyVariable_' + p ;
        var MyHTML     = '<font size="' + p + '">This is text with size depending on the index</font>' ;

        var dummy = $parse(the_string);
        dummy.assign($scope, $sce.trustAsHtml(MyHTML));
```

**Clarification Note**:{{counter}} within the HTML is the parameter "p" passed to the javascript code.

The problem appears to be within the HTML... AngularJS does not like the syntax I'm using within the HTML (i.e. `="MyVariable_{{counter}}"`). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function instead

`ng-bind-html="getHtml(counter)"`

And your javascript would look like this

```
function getHtml(counter) {
   return $scope['MyVariable_' + counter];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dieterg. Beautiful twice: (1) It works, (2) couldn't be simpler!

Comment: Ooops!!!! Sorry @Dieterg but, actually, it PARTIALLY works. The syntax is accepted, but the expected result is not being received. It would appear that the ng-bind-html is not working. What I'm looking for is to insert variable HTML code within the `<div> ... </div>` (see above). What it actually does is to display the resulting string (i.e. "MyVariable_1", "MyVariable_2",...).

Comment: Sorry again. My mistake. Forgot to enclose the returned value as `$scope[...]`. Your answer was perfect!. Thanks again and sorry for the mess.